# Create our own module to display switching views and infinite tab bar

Tags: swift, dependencies, cocoapods, native, resource-cleanup

We want to remove some external dependencies in our project to clean it.
what I am asking is how to create a module to display my data like [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip).
Do you have any idea?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Idea is create own one, use `UICollectionView`s

Comment: you can't do more than what I have done: combining UICollectionView for the Top and UIpageViewController for page at the bottom ;)

Comment: `XLPagerTabStrip` still good for me :)